# Wav2Vec2 kernel size bigger than padding

Tags: python, jupyter, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use pretrained Wav2Vec2 model for speech recognition in my language.
Got it from: https://huggingface.co/facebook/wav2vec2-base-10k-voxpopuli-ft-pl 
Note: I'm working in jupyter notebook. 
First I read the .wav files:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, plot

from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2Processor
from pyctcdecode import build_ctcdecoder
from wavio import read
import jiwer
import arpa

processor=Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained('facebook/wav2vec2-base-10k-voxpopuli-ft-pl')
model=Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained('facebook/wav2vec2-base-10k-voxpopuli-ft-pl')

files={}
for f in Path('nagrania').glob('*.wav'):
  data=read(str(f))
  files[f.stem]=data.data.squeeze().astype('float32')

Fs=data.rate
for name,d in files.items():
  print(f'{name}: {d.size/Fs:0.2f}s')
```

Then I convert it to text:

```
trans={}
for name,data in tqdm(files.items()):
  feats=processor(data,sampling_rate=16000,return_tensors='pt',padding=True)
  in_val = feats.input_values.reshape(feats.input_values.shape[1], 2)
  print(in_val.shape)
  out=model(input_values=in_val)
  predicted_ids=torch.argmax(out.logits,dim=-1)
  sent=processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids)[0]
  trans[name]=sent
```

The shape of *in_val* shows nicely as:
`torch.Size([230400, 2])`

But I'm getting a Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15900\3914553670.py in <module>
      4   in_val = feats.input_values.reshape(feats.input_values.shape[1], 2)
      5   print(in_val.shape)
----> 6   out=model(input_values=in_val)
      7   predicted_ids=torch.argmax(out.logits,dim=-1)
      8   sent=processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids)[0]

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1188         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1189                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1190             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1191         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1192         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\transformers\models\wav2vec2\modeling_wav2vec2.py in forward(self, input_values, attention_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict, labels)
   1680             output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1681             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
-> 1682             return_dict=return_dict,
   1683         )
   1684 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1188         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
...
--> 310                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    311 
    312     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (2). Kernel size: (10). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size
```

How do I reshape my data so padding is calculated accurately or change a kernel size so it matches?

Comment: it looks like you input dimension is  not correct, transpose it

Comment: @amirhm yeah but how

Comment: input values should be FloatTensor of shape (batch_size, sequence_length)) why you are doing such reshape in in_val = feats.input_values.reshape(feats.input_values.shape[1], 2) ? just give the inpt_values